# Include socket.io in the script tag using html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

While using `html` for long time, we used to include the script tags calling for some file within the same folder of the `html` page, or any other folder but we have to include the exact source of it, something like that:

`<script src = "the source of the file and its name"></script>`

Using [socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) website, there is `index.html` file, and the script tag is like that:

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

but in fact the real source of `socket.io.js` file is in the node modules, even-though the website is working well, if I include the real source of this file, the website will crash.

I am really curious about the reason of this strange situation, someone explain it to me, please!

Comment: Did you try the CDN? `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io`

Comment: I already have the library installed in the node modules, but I will try the link @DanielKrom

Comment: you wrap your HTTP server in Socket.IO and it intercepts requests for "/socket.io/socket.io.js" and sends the appropriate response automatically. That is why `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` works

Comment: I got this error: `Refused to execute script from 'https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` @DanielKrom

Comment: @ZainabHammami - Your Socket.IO server will handle serving the correct version of the Socket.IO client library; you should not be using one from elsewhere on the Internet.

Comment: That's right @NikhilNanjappa, I do it like that: `var io = require('socket.io')(http);` but if that is the case then it explains everything

Comment: Have you tried settings type to `application/javascript` or `text/javascript`.

Comment: Yes, if the server is running, `/socket.io/socket.io.js` should be available automatically.

Comment: I don't think that the type has anything  to do with source thing, but I will try though thanks @Wernerson

Comment: great, thanks for the explanation. ^_^ @NikhilNanjappa

Comment: No problem, I will post an answer helping others looking for similar question

Comment: @ZainabHammami Go to the link I wrote, its' not the script end point :)

Comment: @DanielKrom oops, I thought it is the online source, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The website crashes rightly because, your Socket.IO server will handle serving the correct version of the Socket.IO client library; you should not be using one from anywhere else.

**How it works?**

you wrap your HTTP server in Socket.IO like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

and it **intercepts requests** for "/socket.io/socket.io.js" and sends the appropriate response automatically. That is why `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` works and the others don't.

Meaning if the server is running, `socket.io.js` should be readily available.